# Upload file from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple files from jsp using below code:

When I execute it from my local machine I am able to upload in the local systems folder.
But when I access the same from remote machine I am expecting that the files should be uploaded to the same machine where my tomcat exist ,but I get error C:\Files\`folder/file not found`.
Please guide.How to upload it in remote machine or where the tomcat resides

```
boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
     if (!isMultipart) {
     } else {
               FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
               ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
               List items = null;
               try {
                       items = upload.parseRequest(request);
               } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
               }
               Iterator itr = items.iterator();
               while (itr.hasNext()) {
               FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
               if (item.isFormField()) {
               } else {
                       try {
                               String itemName = item.getName();
                               File savedFile = new File("C:\\Files\\a.tiff");
                               item.write(savedFile);  

                       } catch (Exception e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                       }
               }
               }
       }
```

This is the path where I want to upload all files `C:\\Files\\` of the machine where tomcat is.

Comment: check all solution and do let us know.

Comment: you have to use server path not local path("C:\\Files\\a.tiff") for file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your file save path to `new File("C:\\Files\\");` . Even, still you have any problem, then create one folder with `Files` name in another drive `E` or `F` whatever and change your code like `new File("E:\\Files\\");` if you wanna save your file to `E` drive.

**Note:** Since, `C` drive is the primary drive in windows OS, so due to lack of permission, it won't allow to create new file/folder in that drive. So, please try the alternative solution. I mean try to change your file location.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this `new File("C:\\Files\\");` to a foldername on my your remote-server

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at this article

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-monitor-the-progress-of-a-file-upload-to-a-servlet.html?page=2

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm

http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/jsp/tutorial/multipart.xtp

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0d4935/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp/

Comment: please don't do that, OP has minor issue, don't tell him/her to rewrite his/her code to another one.